Flink-SQL dependencies : How to find in Marven Repo
I'm a beginner for apache platforms as well as flink. Im trying to query below Flink-SQL code. I have 2 questions

I need to find the connector "filesystem" (in maven repo or elsewhere)
Is it possible to run these Flink-SQL scripts as scheduled flink-jobs

    -- Create the input table
    CREATE TABLE taxi_rides (
        ride_id BIGINT,
        passenger_count INT,
        start_time TIMESTAMP(3),
        end_time TIMESTAMP(3),
        start_location STRING,
        end_location STRING,
        revenue DOUBLE
    ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'filesystem',
        'path' = 'file:///home/app/taxi_data.parquet',
        'format' = 'parquet'
    );

I need to find the dependency connector and host in Flink

Hi lots of answers to your questions you can find from official documentation.

The file system connector itself is included in Flink and does not require an additional dependency. The corresponding jar can be found in the Flink distribution inside the /lib directory.

You can find here: Flink documentation
chose your version of the doc according to version of Flink you using.
For each format (parquet, avro, etc..) there is dedicated page with instructions and links to download libraries. For parquet in your case.
